# javascript countdown with mouse over reset

Tags: javascript, html, countdowntimer

I am trying to create a timeout on my webpage by counting down from 1min to 0 seconds, then displaying a message. If the user moves the mouse (i.e is still active on the page) the timer gets reset. I cant get the reset function to reset my values. What it is doing is counting down the time faster than before and getting stuck in an unbreakable cycle.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var mins = 1;
            var secs = 0;
            var timer;

            function start()
                {
                    timer = setInterval("update()", 1000);
                }

                function reset() {
                    var mins = 1
                    var secs = 0;
                    var timer;
                    start();
                }

            function update()
                {
                    var timeField = document.getElementById("time");
                    if (secs == 0)
                        {
                            if (mins == 0)
                                {
                                    timeField.innerHTML = "Time's up!";
                                    clearInterval(timer);
                                    alert("Time's up");
                                    return;
                                }

                            mins--;
                            secs = 59;
                        }
                        else 
                            {
                            secs--;
                            }
                        if (secs < 10)
                            {
                            timeField.innerHTML = 'Time left: ' + mins + ':0' + secs;
                        }
                        else
                             {
                             timeField.innerHTML = 'Time left: ' + mins + ':' + secs;
                             }       
                        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="start();" onmousemove="reset();">
        <div id="time" >
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get it to reset the countdown and start again? I am new to javascript so please be patient.

Comment: `timer = window.clearInterval(timer);`

Comment: @PitaJ can you please be a little more specific? Where do I put this in my code etc?

Comment: I'm formulating an answer .. hold on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your reset function,

```
function reset() {
    mins = 1;
    secs = 0;

    window.clearInterval(timer);

    start();
}
```

Declare timer outside of all functions.

Comment: Updated, the timer variable should be declared only after the last timer has been reset.

Comment: Why even declare the timer variable? Just remove that line altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this and what it does it stops the timer but does not reset it to the original time

Comment: inside the reset function, change `var mins = 1; var secs = 0;` to `mins = 1; secs = 0;`

Comment: @ATOzTOA no, because those variables are defined outside the function

Comment: Pita your comment made the above answer work for me. Thanks to you both for your help